# Django: Generate PDFs

Tags: django, pdf-generation

I am currently building a ticketing page using Django. I now have to find the 'best way' to generate a PDF ticket, which ticket buyers can download from our Server.

I looked into different ways and apps including ReportLab in the official documentation. The ticket will include personal information and I am also planning to include a Bar/QR code on the ticket. The question I am struggling with, is which of the available apps is for my purpose the best option. From my first understanding, ReportLab might not be the best solution and I might better generate the ticket from a HTML page.

Before I now dig deeper in documentations I wanted to ask you guys if you have some experience with my objective and can give me some recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've used `wkhtmltopdf` and `pdfkit`.

Read: https://learnbatta.com/blog/django-html-to-pdf-using-pdfkit-and-wkhtmltopdf-5/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate pdf from an HTML page I would suggest you use PhantomJS for this.

Open URL in a subprocess using PhantomJS and direct output to the STDOUT:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['phantomjs', 'rasterize.js', url, '/dev/stdout'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

Then create pdf from the STDOUT output:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
from tempfile import TemporaryFile


with TemporaryFile() as temp_pdf:
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(proc.stdout.read()))
    if img.mode == 'RGBA':
        img = img.convert('RGB')
    img.save(temp_pdf, "PDF", quality=100)
```